# Scrape text from same class tags

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is the HTML I try to get the text from

```
<div class="scoreboardColumn-2OtpR compactHeader-1b8nN"><div>0</div><div>21</div></div><div 
class="scoreboardColumn-2OtpR compactHeader-1b8nN"><div>0</div><div>17</div></div><div 
class="scoreboardColumn-2OtpR compactHeader-1b8nN"><div>0</div><div>14</div></div><div 
class="scoreboardColumn-2OtpR compactHeader-1b8nN"><div>0</div><div>7</div></div><div 
</div></div></div>
```

I would like to get every first div in every second div inside each class separately, for example first divs:

```
0
0
0
0
```

second divs:

```
21
17
14
7
```

Comment: Include some code in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS selector with `:nth-of-type`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div class="scoreboardColumn-2OtpR compactHeader-1b8nN"><div>0</div><div>21</div></div><div 
class="scoreboardColumn-2OtpR compactHeader-1b8nN"><div>0</div><div>17</div></div><div 
class="scoreboardColumn-2OtpR compactHeader-1b8nN"><div>0</div><div>14</div></div><div 
class="scoreboardColumn-2OtpR compactHeader-1b8nN"><div>0</div><div>7</div></div><div 
</div></div></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for first_div in soup.select(".scoreboardColumn-2OtpR > div:nth-of-type(1)"):
    print(first_div.text)

print()

for second_div in soup.select(".scoreboardColumn-2OtpR > div:nth-of-type(2)"):
    print(second_div.text)
```

Prints:

```
0
0
0
0

21
17
14
7
```

---

Or without CSS selectors:

```
for s in soup.find_all(class_="scoreboardColumn-2OtpR"):
    divs = s.find_all("div")
    print("First: {} Second: {}".format(divs[0].text, divs[1].text))
```

Prints:

```
First: 0 Second: 21
First: 0 Second: 17
First: 0 Second: 14
First: 0 Second: 7
```